# TypeError: req.flash is not a function - tried moving middleware

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, flash-message

I am working on a project for school and have been struggling to figure out the cause of

```
TypeError: req.flash is not a function
```

within my routing.

I did exhaustive research and found the following solutions that seemed to have worked for other people, but not me:

- Ensuring `passReqToCallback: true` is set for the local strategy and that the case of 'back' is lowercase.
- I have moved `app.use(flash())` through various locations within the middleware stack and ensured that it came before my routes declaration.

Here is what I've got.
server.js

```
    'use strict';

// Set Up =============================================
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var app = express();

var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');

const PORT = 8081; //For simplicity, since you need root to make it on port 80
const HOSTNAME = "127.0.0.1";

// Config =============================================

require('./app/auth')(passport); //Configure passport

app.use(morgan('dev')); //Logs to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); //Cookies for Auth
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
})); //Get info from html forms
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('view engine', 'html'); //Use the template module to render html
app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile);
app.set('views', __dirname  + "/public/views/pages"); //Instruct the engine of the location of the views


app.use(session({
    secret: 'hashmeupsomethinggood',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
})); //Set default values
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); //Login sessions
app.use(flash()); //For 'Flashing' messages back to client


app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/public')); //Serves static files to client

// Routing =============================================

//Initialize routing with application and configured passport
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport);

// Run ==================================================

//Run the server
var server = app.listen(PORT, HOSTNAME, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});
```

routes.js

```
module.exports = function (app, passport) {

    app.get('/', function (req, res) { //Callback for main pages
        res.render("index.html");
    });

    app.get('/movies', function (req, res) { //Callback for movies display
        res.render("movies.html");
    });

    //Handler for User Login
    app.post('/userlogin',
        passport.authenticate('local-login', {
            failureFlash:true
        },
        function (req, res) {

            if (req.user) {
                console.log("User " + req.user + " logged in");
                res.redirect("index.html"); //redirect but this time will render as logged in
            } else {
                console.log("Login Attempt");
                res.json({flashInfo: req.flash('login')}); //respond with info
            }

        }
        )
    );

};
```

auth.js

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy; //For authenticating email and password
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = require('./connection');

//Set up mysql
var sqlCon = mysql.createConnection(connection);

module.exports = function (passport) {

// Session Setup ==============================================================
// Needed for persistent logins

    //Serialize user id to identify session
    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        console.log("[Auth] Checking Login of " + user.EMAIL);
        if (user.ID) //User logging in is a customer OR employee - check both
            done(null, user.ID);
        else
            done(null, user.SSN);
    });

    //Obtain user object based on session user id
    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {

        connection.query( //todo: add support for the employee here too
            "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE EMAIL = ?",
            [id],
            function (err, results, field) {
                done(err, results[0]);
            }
        );
    });

// Login ==============================================================

    passport.use(
        'local-login',
        new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true
        },
        function (req, email, password, done) {
            console.log("[Auth] Checking Login of " + email);
            //Query for customer credentials
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE EMAIL = ?",
                [email],
                function (err, results) {
                    console.log("[Auth] First query");
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("[Auth] Error Accessing Database");
                        return done(err); //Error accessing database
                    } else {
                        if (results.length == 0) { //Could possibly be an employee logging in

                            //Query for employee credentials
                            connection.query("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE EMAIL = ?",
                                [email],
                                function (err, results) {
                                    if (err) {
                                        return done(err); //Query failed
                                    } else {
                                        if (results.length == 0) {//Does it exist in employee either?
                                            console.log("[Auth] Could not find user");
                                            return done(null, false, req.flash("login", "A user by that name does not exist!"));
                                        }
                                        return passwordCheck(results[0]); //Verify password

                                    }

                                }

                            )
                        }
                        return passwordCheck(results[0]);
                    }
                });

            //Determines the validity of a password and returns the corresponding verify callback function
            var passwordCheck = function (result) {
                console.log("[Auth] Verifying Password of " + email);
                if (result.PASSWORD == password)
                    return done(null, result);
                else
                    return done(null, false, req.flash("login", "Incorrect Password"));

            };
        }
        )
    );

// Register ==============================================================

    passport.use(
        'local-register',
        new LocalStrategy({
                usernameField: 'email',
                passwordField: 'password',
                passReqToCallback : true
            },
            function (req, email, password, done) {
                //Grab form data
                var data = [req.body.fname, req.body.lname, req.body.bday, req.body.gender, email, password] //Form data

                //Check that input isnt empty
                if (data.includes("")) {
                    console.log("User %s registed with empty form", email);
                    return done(null, false, req.flash("register", "Please make sure not to leave anything blank"));
                }

                //Check that we arent making a duplicate account
                connection.query(
                    "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE EMAIL = ?",
                    [email],
                    function (err, results) {
                        if (err) {
                            done(err);
                        }

                        //Check if the email has been taken
                        if (results.length > 0) {
                            done(null, false, req.flash("register", "That email has already been taken"));
                        } else {

                            //User for session
                            var newUser = {
                                EMAIL: data[4],
                                PASSWORD: data[5],
                                FNAME:data[0],
                                LNAME: data[1],
                                BDAY: data[2],
                                SEX: data[3]
                            };

                            connection.query(
                                "INSERT INTO customer(FNAME, LNAME, BDATE, SEX, EMAIL, `PASSWORD`) " +
                                "VALUES (?, ?, STR_TO_DATE(?, '%m/%d/%y'), ?, ?, ?)",
                                data,
                                function (err, results) {
                                    newUser.ID = results.insertId; //Add ID
                                    return done(null, newUser);
                                }
                            )

                        }

                    })


            }
        )
    );

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I accidentailly used the variable connection instead of sqlCon when querying